# db.create_all() not generating db

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to test Flask with SQLAlchemy and I stumbeld accross this problem. First, I have to note that I read all of the related threads and none of them solves my problem. I have a problem that db.create_all() doesn't generate the table I defined. I have model class in file person.py:

```
from website import db


class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    width = db.Column(db.Integer)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer)
    agent = db.Column(db.String)
    user_data_dir = db.Column(db.String)
```

And in my website.py which is the file from where I launch the app:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# create the extension
db = SQLAlchemy()

def start_server(host, port, debug=False):
    from person import Person

    # create the app
    app = Flask(__name__,
                static_url_path='',
                static_folder='web/static',
                template_folder='web/templates')
    # configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database0.db"
    # initialize the app with the extension
    db.init_app(app)

    print('initialized db')
    print('creating tables...')

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        db.session.add(Person(username="example33"))
        db.session.commit()

        person = db.session.execute(db.select(Person)).scalar()
        print('persons')
        print(person.username)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

I think the problem might be that the Person class is not importing properly, because when I put the class inside the start_server function it executes fine and creates the table, but I don't know why this is happening. I followed all the advice and imported it before everything, and also I share the same db object between the 2 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this but this is the only way I could get this to work. You need to create a `models.py` file or w.e you wanna call it. Then all your database stuff goes in there. The db engine, ALL your models and a function to initialize it all. The reason is, you are having import issues where `Person` is imported but not fully and so the db doesn't have it in its metadata.

`models.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    width = db.Column(db.Integer)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer)
    agent = db.Column(db.String)
    user_data_dir = db.Column(db.String)

# All other models

def initialize_db(app: Flask):
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import models


def start_server(host, port, debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database0.db"
    # initialize the app with the extension
    models.initialize_db(app)
    db = models.db
    
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.add(models.Person(username="example33"))
        db.session.commit()

        person = db.session.execute(db.select(models.Person)).scalar()
        print('persons')
        print(person.username)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all),
which explains that the function will

> Create all tables stored in this metadata.

That leads me to believe Person is not associated with the db metadata.

You mentioned

> when I put the class inside the start_server function it ... creates the table

Your `from person import Person` is nice enough,
but I suspect we wanted a simple `import person`.
In many apps the idiom would be `import models`.

Failing that, you may be able to point
`create_all` in the right direction
with this optional parameter:

> tables – Optional list of Table objects, which is a subset of the total tables in the MetaData

---

Please [let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
what technical approach worked for you.

Comment: You can't do a `import person` this would lead to a circular reference since its reliant on the `db` variable in `main`. At least that's what happens to me when I do that.